# Angular UI Grid adjust row height based on content

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

Is it possible to adjust the row height in the grid to display the entire content?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to override the bootstrap css

```
.ngCell  {
  display : table-cell;
  height: auto !important;
  overflow:visible;
  position: static;
}

.ngRow {
  display : table-row;
  height: auto !important;
  position: static;
}

.ngCellText{
  height: auto !important;
  white-space: normal;
  overflow:visible;
}
```

Comment: Can you create a plunkr or fiddler for this? I'm not able to make it work.

Comment: You are using the old grid, I'm talking about the new grid that is still in beta. Do you have any ideas on that? Thanks for your help Aditya!

Comment: Can you provide me the link of directive that you are trying to use?

Comment: .ui-grid-cell  {
  display : table-cell;
  height: auto !important;
  overflow:visible;
  position: static;
}

.ui-grid-row {
  display : table-row;
  height: auto !important;
  position: static;
}

.ui-grid-cell-contents{
  height: auto !important;
  white-space: normal;
  overflow:visible;
}

Comment: Not sure if it will work or not. I will try to explore this new grid. Thanks for introducing, this looks much better :)

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. If I scroll the rows disappear. Take a look here http://plnkr.co/edit/JkVXFJumRWXdc4BGwuxp?p=preview

Comment: I have got the same problem described by Shak Smith. Is there a way to do it right now?